# Continuity of function that depends on rationality of argument

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x, & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
x^2, & x \notin \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
$$

Is $f$ continuous at $0$? Is $f$ continuous at $1$?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Check if the definition of continuity is satisfied?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what level of rigor you are looking for, but the question ultimately comes down to does:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = f(0) $$

and

$$ \lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = f(1). $$

If you are looking for a $\epsilon-\delta$ proof then take $\delta_1$ from $f_1(x) = x$ (which is $\delta_1 = \epsilon$) and $\delta_2$ from $f_2(x) = x^2$ and for your $f(x)$ you can take $\delta = \min \{\, \delta_1, \delta_2\, \}$.  You should try to check these details yourself.

While we are at it, you should note that the points of continuity are at the points $x$ where $x = x^2$.  You should also convince yourself (or prove) that $f$ is not continuous at any other point.